# Angular 2: Swapping between different components without destroying them

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build a window manager with Angular 2. Basically, I want to be able to swap between windows (that are components injected in a router outlet) without losing their states. For instance, I'm editing a product information form when I change to a customers' list, then I come back to the product form and I find it in the same state... Is it possible?

Comment: In other words, is there a way of preventing the components from being destroyed when we navigate to another component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I surpassed this requirement.

Once the route changes, the windows components are destroyed. So, to save state in between those windows instances, I had to manually store it into an injected service.

To store and load the state for each window component, I used the life-cycle hooks that are provided by the router: onActivate(next, prev) and onDeactivate(next, prev).

**EDIT**

Meanwhile, I've opened an [issue on Angular 2 github repo](http://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5275) requesting this feature.

Comment: how did you save the state ? using `window` object ? I can't make it work.

Comment: I have the state stored in a service which is injected into my views

Comment: I understand the `service` part but what did you store exactly. I've failed with `class's instance` and `window` object , what else am I supposed to store ?

Comment: Could you provide a plunker that demonstrates what you did?  It would be very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Checkout `canReuse` on the router: [canReuse in angular2 api docs](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/CanReuse-interface.html)

If you specify it the router wont destroy your component when switching away from it.

Comment: Hi Dennis, you're right... Looking at the documentation, you are absolutely right! But if you dive into the implementation details(https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b0009f03d510370d9782cf76197f95bb40d16c6a/modules/angular2/src/router/router_outlet.ts), you will find this:

"If the new child component has a different Type than the existing child component, this will resolve to `false`. You can't reuse an old component when the new component is of a different Type."
   
According to their code, the reuse hook is only triggered if we are navigating to and from a component of the same type.

Comment: hmmm. I'd have to see this in practice to understand. The way I read it was if you registered something to a component you couldn't change the type later. ['Cars'] always goes to CarsCmp if being reused.

Comment: I've looked at it a bit more and it seems you are right about that restriction. I'm not sure if that's true without testing it but it looks like you cant reUse two different component types in the same route. Seems like a big thing not to mention though.

Comment: Dennis, I've opened a feature request regarding this situation. Have a look on it here (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5275)

Comment: 404 your link is dead

Comment: @Ced this is way way old code, uses a totally different router