# Angular2 - changing location without triggering a Route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a view which uses service to load a list of items. I'm always displaying only one item, moving between items with << >> buttons.

Is there any way to change address in browser's address bar and to add record to browser's history without triggering Angular's routing system?

I know that if I use:

```
location.go('users/3');
```

it will do above-mentioned things, but it also triggers Angular's route system, which in turn calls my services again.

Edit:

it seems like location's function

```
location.replaceState('users/3');
```

is getting close to what I want to do - it changes url in browser without triggering any Angular internals, unfortunately it replaces latest location in history instead of pushing the new one at the top.

Comment: Like @Günter Zöchbauer said, if you declare the provider ONLY in a top level it doesn't matter how many times you inject it, it won't get recreated. Check this to see if it helps to what you are looking for: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/AuxRoute-class.html there's no much documentation yet but I believe it is meant for these kind of scenarios.

Comment: There was maybe some misunderstanding. The service is not recreated, but called every time route is triggered - Component where the service is injected is recreated (ngOnInit called). But again, I've found location.replaceState which does the more important half of what I want to accomplish, now I'd like to find how to solve history being overwritten when calling replaceState function

Comment: Yea, I do believe AuxRoute was meant for what you need to do.

Comment: You don't provide information about how that service is integrated into your application. `canReuse` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648355/angular-2-swapping-between-different-components-without-destroying-them might also help. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanReuse-interface.html

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer could you add the canReuse part also to your answer as an alternative, it was what I was looking for and I almost missed it since it was hidden in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't add the service to the components `provider:` list you won't get a new instance for this service. Make the service global instead by only registering in `bootstrap(AppComponent, [MyGlobalService])`.

Implementing [CanReuse](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanReuse-interface.html) see also [Angular 2: Swapping between different components without destroying them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648355/angular-2-swapping-between-different-components-without-destroying-them) might help to prevent re-initializing components when the same route is reused.