# Angular2 CustomReuseStrategy creates new instance of component when routing with parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using Angular2 CustomReuseStrategy class to save a component instance. 
When I first route to a component a new instance is created. This works as expected. However, when I route to the same component with new parameters, a new instance of that component is created and the onInit functions execute again. I would like the component to use the same instance, but update the URL parameters. Any ideas? I am stuck on this one.

Here are my routes.

```
{ path: 'tiles', component: DisplayTileData },
{ path: 'tiles/:master/:filters', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: DisplayTileData }
```

Here are the methods that navigate to these routes.

```
addNewMasterPath(newMasterVariable) {
    this.master = this.master + '-' + newMasterVariable;
    var newMap = this.variable.map(items => { return items}).join('-');
    this.router.navigate(['tiles', this.master, newMap]);
}

onSelectAddNewParameter(newParameter) {
    this.variable.push(newParameter);
    var newMap = this.variable.map(items => { return items}).join('-');
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/tiles/this.master/newMap');
}
```

Just to be clear the behavior is the same whether I use router.navigate or router.navigateByUrl.

Comment: You should provide your custom reuse strategy code

Comment: Do not know if it helps, but have you tried to create a urlTree: `var urlTree= this.router.createUrlTree(["tiles",this.master,newMap]); this.router.navigateByUrl(urlTree);`?

Comment: Duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686036/angular-2-route-with-parameters-re-initializing-component-oninit ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source code here:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.4.1/modules/%40angular/router/src/router.ts#L293-L798

I don't think there's a way to navigate that doesn't reload the component.  Would it be possible to not have a more specific route for those parameters, and pass the query information to the component through the @Input?