# Get param['id'] on layout component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I need to get the route param id on layout component.

**routing.ts:**

```
{
 path: 'car/:id',
 component: CarDetailComponent,
 canActivate: [AuthGuard]
}
```

Briefly I'm doing this to get Car ID on my **layout.component.ts:**

```
 public param_id: string;
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      if (params['id']) {
        this.param_id = this.route.params['id'];
        console.log(params['id']); // undefined
      }
    });
 }
```

param_id returns undefined all the time.

***Note: I need all params id whenever change the page, not only car's. So I call params on layout.component (it's a common page that includes router-outlet)***

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the same code in a ngOnInit function? (implements OnInit) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686036/angular-2-route-with-parameters-re-initializing-component-oninit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the layout components route is not containing the param id.

You will have to access the children of `this.route` and iterate them to get the id.

something like

```
this.route.children.forEach(child => {
   child.params.subscribe(...); // do what you wanna do
}
```

This is getting more complex when the children are also having children. I'd recommend to use something like [ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/platform) or an uni-directional [singleton service](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services), if you really always need to access id parameter from your layout-component.

Comment: Don't forget to store subscriptions, they must be unsubscribe when your component is destroyed, otherwise you will end up having a memory leak.

Comment: Is it a bad idea to use forEach instead of subscribe? It also works.

Comment: Subscribe will keep emitting changes if you open the url with car/id with different ids, while forEach won't.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get this undefined, is on this line:

```
this.param_id = this.route.params['id'];
```

Change it on:

```
this.param_id = params['id'];
```

And all will works

Comment: unfortunately, that does't work. i guess +params['id'] is only for getting data as number not  as string.

Comment: Ou sorry. Then try to do this without plus

Comment: Then you will get the string. I little bit chacnge my answer

Comment: No, it does't even work -- if (params['id']) {} -- block above that code.

Comment: Maybe try to move it from constructor to ngOnInit ?

Comment: Anf do you recieve any answer above if block ?

Comment: params return empty object above if block. I tried it in ngOnInit, same result.

Comment: I am sorry for this silly question.. but on what route you try to go ? You whitr it like car/1 and so on ? Or how ?

Comment: car/1 or admin/2 or flower/x it doesn't matter. I want 1 or 2 or x when i go these routes. If I go dummy-page/:id, i should get the :id. I call the route.params on layout component because of that. It is a common component that every other component uses.

Comment: think about a button on header of the page and this header is never reloading when route change. and when you click this button you want to get the output of current route's param['id'].

Comment: I think i understand you. But it could't be done... Because you listen a specific route. I mean you need to do this in every component where you try to listen params... sorry i don't know any way to do what you whant

Comment: In your header component you could get only params of the that route where you implement it.. so if you have header on route /car you could get params only on /car/:id