# Angular 2 Retaining Component Values Across Multiple Components

Tags: angular

If I have a list of checkboxes on Component 1 and I check the first checkbox. How do I retain the checked items when I navigate to other components?

Example:

1.) Navigate to Component 1 and check a checkbox for Item 1.

2.) Then I click a button which routes me to Component 2.

3.) Now I click another a button which routes me back to Component 1.```

Result: I want Item 1 to be checked.

How would I achieve that?

Comment: You have to use sharedService and make sure that only single instance is shared among components. I could help you with `Plunker` but it will be very time consuming for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: Swapping between different components without destroying them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648355/angular-2-swapping-between-different-components-without-destroying-them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return true from `routerCanReuse()` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanReuse-interface.html then the same component instance will be reuse instead of creating a new one.

Alternatively (as mentioned by micronyks) you can register a service in a common parent (might be the root component or `bootstrap()` for application wide sharing) and store and retrieve the values from there.